# Why isn't my program inputing chars into 2d array from file?

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I'm trying to input chars into a 2d array from a file, but its not putting anything into the array. When I try to print it out I just get a bunch of symbols that look like this - ╠

Here is an example that produces the same error:

test file looks like this:

```
g g g g g g g g g g
g g g t t t t t t g
g g g t t g t t g g
g t t g g t g g t g
g t t g g t g g t g
g t g t t g t t g g
g t t g g t g g t g
g t t g g t g g t g
g t g t t g t t g g
g g g g g g g g g g
```

Example that produces same error:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    ifstream inFile;
    char myArray[15][15];

    inFile.open("C:\test\Ch5p_fa.asc");

    int rows = 10;
    int columns = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            inFile.get(myArray[i][j]);
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << myArray[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();

cin.get();

}
```

Comment: The file is not getting opened because you need to escape the backslashes. `"C:\\test\\Ch5p_fa.asc"`. You should always check that the file was actually opened.

Comment: Sorry, this is just an example- the actual program has a real file path

Comment: Does your real file has spaces between characters and lines breaks as your example does?

Comment: Yes, this is copied from the actual test file

Comment: So your array is too small because you have 20 characters in each line if you don't need the space character and break line characters you have to skip them and not read them into your array. Also if you are not getting any correct character from the file, check if your file is saving the characters as wide characters.

Comment: And I think you have to add the 'std::fstream::in ' flag when you open a file for reading  using fstream library

Comment: @user3196144 `std::ifstream` defaults to using the right flags for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int main() {

    ifstream inFile;
    char myArray[15][15];

    inFile.open("C:\\test\\Ch5p_fa.asc", std::fstream::in);   // std::fstream::in allows you to read from the file.

    int rows = 10;
    int columns = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)  {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            inFile.get(myArray[i][j]);
            inFile.get();                       // Skeem unwonted char
        }
    }

    inFile.close();

    cin.get();

}
```

If you need the spaces just make column twice as big.

Comment: *Hangs head in shame* Right, spaces ARE characters too, huh? Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 1):

Your columns are two times smaller, as they dont account for white characters. You could write your first loop as follows for example, ising [isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) to check if your current character is alphanumeric:

```
char tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns*2; j++) {
        tmp = inFile.get();
        if (isalpha(tmp))
        {
            myArray[i][j/2] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`inFile.get(myArray[i][j])` will read all the characters, including spaces. Use the `>>` stream operator instead, this will skip the spaces:

```
if (!inFile)
    return 0;

//initialize the array
memset(myArray, 0, 15 * 15);

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        if (!(inFile >> myArray[i][j]))
        {
            //break the loop
            i = rows;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```